# How to convert input from cmd to unicode in Python 2.7

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have a input statement like this.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
myentry = raw_input("Enter a letter").decode("iso-8859-1").encode("utf-8")

if myentry == "ö":
    print(myentry)
if myentry == "ä":
    print("ääää")
```

The problem is when I enter ö or ä nothing happens and the program terminates.

I am using cmd under windows 7. I am saving the script as utf-8

Comment: Try `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd have been using python 2.x, you could try to claim that the letters are unicode symbols, so it'd be something like this:

```
if myentry == u"ö":
    print(myentry)
if myentry == u"ä":
    print(u"ääää")
```

In the python 3.x there should also be something like this

Comment: I get unicode equal comparison failed when I try that.

Comment: Hmm, but your first code actually works! (Just don't forget to remove the brackets after "print"^ they are unnecessary in the python 2.x

Comment: are you on a windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

Your default encodings is probably set to `ascii`. You can change it to `utf-8` like this:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

After starting the program the `setdefaultencoding()` function gets deleted. Reloading `sys` brings it back so you can change the encoding. So this is kind of a hack and probably not the ideal way of solving this problem. Now you should be able to read your input like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
myentry = raw_input("Enter a letter").decode("utf-8")

if myentry == "ö":
    print(myentry)
if myentry == "ä":
    print("ääää")
```

This works for me (using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu)

Comment: Then I get ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Okay, then your default encoding is probably `ascii`. Mine is `utf-8`. That's why it worked for me. You can check it like this: `import sys`
 `sys.getdefaultencoding()`. Does it work if you use `decode("utf-8")` instead of `encode("utf-8")` ? (still without the iso ... function). That should work according to [this](http://blog.webforefront.com/archives/2011/02/python_ascii_co.html) page.

Comment: nope, then I get utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: I gave up. I think I will just update to python 3 :)

Comment: Okay, Good luck :)